# A div-type element that doesn't affect layout for inserting elements with JS

Tags: html, css

I am using Twitter Bootstrap for my grid system. I have a JS script that gets a list of items from an XML file. Every item that I get from this file should be inserted into the grid with it's own column. To make it easier to insert these items into the DOM, I use a div called news-results and just append it each time the script loops through the next item in the XML.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Recent News</h1>
    <div id="news-results">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3>{news_title}</h3>
                    <p>{news_body}</p>
                    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                        <div class="card-link">
                            <h6>Posted on {news_date}</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-link">
                            <a href="{news_link}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem with this is that the news-results div seems to be affecting the layout of the grid. The cells stack on top of each other instead of the way they should be. If I copy the HTML of only the newly inserted news items and insert it into the page without the news-results div, it works fine.

Is there an element I can use to easily identify to the script where in the page the elements should be inserted?

Here is a JS fiddle to demonstrate. If you remove the news-results tag, you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution that works for me.

```
#news-results {
  display: contents;
}
```

It basically makes the div act as strictly a placeholder for the content HTML.